# Haskell: Expected type: [Char] Actual type: [[Char]]

Tags: haskell

I recently started learning Haskell and in my program I am getting the following error:

```
    Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
Expected type: [Char]
  Actual type: [[Char]]
In the first argument of ‘head’, namely ‘input’
In the first argument of ‘magi’, namely ‘(head input)’
```

My code looks like this:

```
vocals = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u","y"]
vocal o
  | elem o vocals == True = True --return true if the letter is a vowel
  | elem o vocals == False = False --else false

magi konsonant = [konsonant] ++ "o" ++ [konsonant]

rovarsprak input
  |length input == 0 = ""
  |length input > 0 && vocal (head input) == False = magi (head input) ++ rovarsprak (tail input)
  |length input > 0 && vocal (head input) == True = head input : rovarsprak (tail input)
```

As I understand, I am getting the error because of my input to the head function is [[char]] instead of [char], but I don't understand why the input to head is a [[char]].
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `vocal` has type:

```
vocal :: String -> Bool
```

This is because `vocals` is a **list of `String`s**, and thus `elem` will here check if a string is in the list of strings.

and therefore Haskell derives that since you call `vocal (head input)`, `input` itself should be a list of `String`s.

We can easily alter this into:

```
vocals = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
```

Or shorter:

```
vocals = "aeiouy"
```

That being said, your code is quite chaotic. We can rewrite it into:

```
vocals :: [Char]
vocals = "aeiouy"

vocal :: Char -> Bool
vocal = flip elem vocals                   -- pointfree function

magi :: Char -> String
magi konsonant = konsonant : 'o' : [konsonant]

rovarsprak :: String -> String
rovarsprak "" = ""                         -- use patterns
rovarsprak (h:t)                           -- use patterns to unpack
    | vocal h = h : rovarsprak t           -- == True is not necessary
    | otherwise = magi h ++ rovarsprak t   -- use otherwise
```

The line `vocal = flip elem vocals` works as follows: `flip` takes as input a function `f` that takes two arguments `x` and `y`. It then turns it into a function that takes two arguments `y` and `x` (so the arguments are flipped).

What we want is to call `elem o vocals`. This is equivalent to `flip elem vocals o`. Now by using *eta*-reduction, we can omit the `o` (both in the head and the body of the clause).

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
 But I dont quite what does the line `vocal = flip elem vocals` do?